# How many different permutations from 9A's, 7B's and 6c's have no B's adjacent to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I know how to solve this problem if I have only 2B's :
I will treat 'BB' as one symbol and I will put it in $(9+2+6)-1=16$ different ways .
Then I have that there are $N_{BB}=21*C(14, 9)$ diferrent permutations that do have 'BB' (put 'BB' first, A's after, C's with one way) therefore $$X= C(16,9)*C(7,2)-21*C(14, 9)$$ .

**BUt what about when I have 7B's**?
I have to take into account all the ways that 7B's could be next to each other somehow :
BB_B_B_B_B_B____
or
BBB_BB______BB_
or
_***BBBBBBB***
and so on.

Comment: Hint. Arrange the A's and C's in some order. Then choose the 7 spaces to insert the B's. Check that this method gives you the same answer as your calculation when there are just 2 B's.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ denote the number of ways that $7$ B's can be distributed in $22$ positions so that none of the B's are adjacent to each other.

Then, regardless of what satisfying distribution of B's are taken, you will then need to select $6$ positions, from the remaining $15$ positions, for the $6$ C's.  This selection will be done without replacement, where order of selection is deemed unimportant.

So, the final computation will be

$$F \times \binom{15}{6}.$$

Therefore, the problem reduces to enumerating $F$.  This enumeration is a straightforward **Stars and Bars** problem.
For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Consider any satisfying distribution of the $7$ B's in the $22$ positions.  The distribution will create $8$ regions, which are before the first $B$, and after each of the $7$ B's.

Each such satisfying distribution will correspond to a solution to the following problem:

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_8 = 15.$
- $x_1, x_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_7 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$

The 3rd bullet-point above accommodates that none of the B's can be adjacent to each other.

Use the change of variable:
$y_i = x_i - 1 ~: ~i \in \{2,3,\cdots,7\}.$

Then, the computation of $F$ can be represented by the alternate problem:

- $x_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_7 + x_8 = 15 - 6 = 9.$
- $x_1, x_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $y_2, y_3, \cdots, y_7 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

By Stars and Bars Theory,

$$F = \binom{9 + 7}{7} = \binom{16}{7}.$$

Therefore, the desired computation is

$$\binom{16}{7} \times \binom{15}{6}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without stars and bars

First place the $A's\,$ and $\,C's\,$ (bullets) in $\large\binom{15}6$ ways

$\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow$

The $B's$ can now be placed at the uparrows in $\large\binom{16}7$ ways to give an answer of $\large\binom{15}6\binom{16}7$ ways